# Serverless Framework - How to disable all API routes to an AWS Lambda function and use SNS only

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am using the Serverless Framework and wish to create an AWS Lambda function that is only triggered through SNS notifications.

```
functions:
  myHandler:
    handler: handler.foo
    events:
      - sns: mySNSTopic
```

However this generates a POST route:

```
Serverless: Routes for myHandler:
Serverless: POST /{apiVersion}/functions/my-app-staging-myHandler/invocations
```

Why does it do this? How can I disable it?

**Update** I see that it is now only in offline mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After toying with it I see that it's only created by Serverless Offline and not pushed live. I used by sls to invoke the Lambda by itself using `sls lambda invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it do that? I don’t know.

How can I disable it? I can sort of help you with that. I don’t know how to stop the POST route from being generated, but I can show you how to stop anything other than SNS from invoking your function.

You can [attach a resource-based IAM policy to your lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html). Specifically, you can attach a policy that denies all access to invoke the lambda function except for allowing SNS to invoke it.

The policy would look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Sid": "InvokeMyLambdaFunctionOnlyFromSNS",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "Service": [
                "sns.amazon.com"
            ]
        },
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:region:AccountID:function:function_name"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I figured out it was sls offline for its CLI commands. The deploy is not as verbose so wasn't clear to me initially it was a local thing. Thank you for this though as that can come handy.